# Talend Display null as empty array

Tags: json, talend

I new at talend stuck with a basic issue ,any help would be really appreicated
I have a talend esb job that let me query my database via get request

Job Flow:
[image: Job Flow]

Job flow is like:-

```
Trestrequest==>tflowIterate==>Redshift==>txmlmap==>trestresponse
```

Call:

```
localhost/restaurant?rest_id=305&from_date=%272016-10-12%27&to_date=%272016-10-18%27&_=1476875037045
```

get the result(Json response)

```
{"root":{"combo3":[{"class1":11963,"class2":12405,"class3":13050,"count":12}
```

which is perfect and what is required

How can I handle `404 exception` for Talend ESB and display 
`{}` (in web page or web browser)

Right now I only see empty webpage as result but how can I replace it with 
`{}` (in web page or web browser)

Comment: Could you try to be more specific about  your question ? Where do you want to handle exception ? which web page are you talking about ? what did you try ? what kind of response is sent in your RESTResponse ?

Comment: the answer that i was looking for was provided in another link
posting it below(for refrence of others)
https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=53647